# Running Batch file from a server location

Tags: batch-file, server

I am in the process of reconfiguring my home computer system. Simply speaking I have been running a prgramme *[PortfolioSlicer]* on a desktop

I am now intending to run the desktop programme from a laptop, with the desktop being a network location.

On the desktop PortfolioSlicer is located as
C:\PortfolioSlicer
this is mapped onto my laptop as
\DESKTOP-AG0S799\C Drive Desktop\PortfolioSlicer

To run the batch [UpdatePSData.bat] on my Desktop I have created a shortcut to run the batch.

When a I run the shortcut from my laptop I get all sorts of error messages. The initial error is "CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory."

On googling the issue I am directed to “net use”. Unfortunately, I am all “at sea” here.

This is the shortcut that works without an issue when run directly on my desktop.

*Target: C:\PortfolioSlicer\UpdatePSData.bat*

*Start In: C:\PortfolioSlicer*

I have mapped \DESKTOP-AG0S799\C Drive Desktop\PortfolioSlicer as drive Z:

Can some one help me in modifying the shortcut on my laptop to run the batch on drive Z:

Comment: If you've mapped the location to `Z`, then you shouldn't be using its UNC path, you should be using the drive letter you've mapped it to, i.e. `Z:\UpdatePSData.bat`

Comment: @Compo thanks for your response. Yes that is logical, but I had steered away from that as I was working through trying to find an answer due to errors created in running the batch.

Comment: You've only asked one question, and that is what I've commented on. Any other errors, are outside of the scope of your asked question, and as you've not mentioned them anyhow, as impossible for us to answer.